# Как сделать выборку по расписанию занятости?

Tags: mysql, алгоритм

База Mysql

Есть база занятости менеджера(время начала работы и примерная продолжительность в часах):
**manager_id | date_time_start | duration**

Вида:
123 | 2020-11-17 12:00:00 | 4
123 | 2020-11-17 19:00:00 | 2

Есть база задач(время начала задачи и примерная продолжительность в часах):
**task_id | date_time_start | duration**

Вида:
1 | 2020-11-17 11:00:00 | 2
2 | 2020-11-17 17:00:00 | 1

Подскажите как переделать базу и составить запрос, чтобы вывести менеджеру только те задачи, которые удовлетворяют следующему условию:

- интервал времени работы новой задачи не должен попадать в интервал текущих задач менеджера
- время начала новой задачи должно быть не раньше чем через 20 минут после окончания предыдущей задачи.
- время окончания новой задачи должно быть быть не меньше чем за 20 минут до начала текущих задач менеджера.

Также надо выводить в обратную сторону, чтобы по задаче вывести всех доступных менеджеров для данной задачи по критериям выше.

Может есть готовые алгоритмы для такой задачи? Базу пока можно переделать, чтобы это работало быстро. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Собственно самое обычное (не)пересечение интервалов. Раздвигаете интервалы у менеджера на 20 минут, а потом отбираете непересекающиеся задачи (количество интервалов менеджера, пересекающихся с временем задачи, равно нулю).

Comment: *Базу пока можно переделать, чтобы это работало быстро.* Добавьте виртуальные вычисляемые поля - завершения задачи, границ времени задачи с учётом "20 минут".

Comment: @Akina спасибо, кажется, то что надо. Изначально думалось, что проверок намного больше.